# Angular 7 SCSS Doesn't Keep CSS Custom Properties

Tags: css, angular, sass, css-variables, angular-compiler

I'm trying to use CSS Custom properties in my Angular 7 app but am running into issues where building down to css gets rid of the property that is set to a CSS variable.

SCSS

```
:root {
  --my-test-var: red;
}

.testclass123 {
  height: 150px;
  background: var(--my-test-var);
}
```

Builds down to:

```
:root {
  --my-test-var: red;
}

.testclass123 {
  height: 150px;
}
```

If I use a fallback options like `var(--my-test-var, purple);` then `.testclass123` will also have property `background: purple;`

My Angular version is 7.2.7 and Angular Material 7.3.7

Comment: Are you doing it in global styles and not component-level?

Comment: Ideally I'd be able to use them globally. Currently I've tried both the global stylesheet and component styles

Comment: Can you reproduce it on StackBlitz? Also, I suppose that you may run some sort of pet project and if it so it would be better to switch onto 8th version (why use obsolete)? Anyway, to answer this question we need either a StackBlitz example or GitHub project to investigate

Comment: Also, just for try - try to change `red` onto some hex code

Comment: I got it just now! I had to surround my css variable like ```#{var(--my-test-var)}``` and that made it stick around.

Comment: Kind of weird since you are not dealing with SCSS variables

Comment: It works with latest version. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p7h5vv Maybe it's worth deleting `node_modules` and running `npm i` to reinstall sass compiler

Comment: I'll mess around some more and see if I can figure out why it's slightly different for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `SCSS` as global style you can define like this the color.
This is the best approach.

```
$product: red;
```

And then only you call when you need like this.

```
background-color: $product;
```